# RegEx to allow anything except blanks or all spaces?

Tags: regex

I want to allow anything and everything..

except blank entries (NULL, zero characters, whatever you want to call it) and also blank spaces of any length should not be allowed.

This is essentially what I would do with a TRIM() function if I were coding in a language, but I have a need to do this with only regex.

Thank you!

Comment: To clarify, if the user simply enters a bunch of spaces into the field then I want to stop them from doing so in addition to stopping them from entering no characters in the field at all.

Comment: [^\s]+ should do the trick

Comment: @FujiBob What about spaces in between non-space characters? Should they also be forbidden? And what language are you using?

Comment: "" = invalid
"    " = invalid
"  This is a sentence with spaces  " = valid. Also, this is RegEx for the EJS TreeGrid control

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about this regex:

```
(?!^ +$)^.+$
```

This will make sure that:

1. Input is not empty or null
2. Input doesn't only have 1 or more spaces
3. Spaces in between non-space characters are allowed

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/x2MU1fbAhE

Comment: Thank you! This one ALMOST works. I do want to allow blank spaces in the beginning or the end of the string. So: " this is ok ". Right now it works for everything I need it to except for if a user has spaces in the beginning of the string. How can it be updated to allow spaces in the beginning and end, too?

Comment: @FujiBob: I made a small edit in my regex for that case. See new demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/x2MU1fbAhE also.

Answer (score 2):

Mr. Bob, I would like to know what language you are working in? I know if you are using C# there are plenty of great utilities for matching regular expressions or handling user input. However, without that knowledge the best I could offer is this:

`[\S]+`

This will match any non-whitespace character. Then you could stitch each match together. If you provide the language you are working with, I can give you a better answer.

Comment: This will also block in-between spaces like `abc def`

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's this creature here: [EJS TreeGrid - Link to the ResultMask definition](http://longboo.com/demo/ejs-treegrid/Doc/CellEdit.htm#CResultMask). I am using PHP, Javascript, jQuery.

Comment: Well, the super easy way would be to use the regex I suggested as input validation. So, on the POST or GET you would check the input against the regex, if there is a match then you would submit the match as input, else you would display an error message. 

You also mentioned something along the lines of not allowing users to enter whitespace at all? Is this something you still want to look into?

EDIT: That man page made my eyes bleed, so I will admit I didn't read it. Also, please tell me if I am misunderstanding your question.

Comment: "When input value collides with ResultMask, the ResultText alert message is displayed and editing continues." That is the important piece from that ugly webpage. To me that means that whatever we put into that ResultMask='' field should make it so only non-blank entries can make it through.

Comment: I seeeee. Ok, well, I'll keep an eye on this thread. It looks like anubhava has a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, to match all non-white space characters you would use:

```
[^\s]+
```

However, if you are looking for an equivalent to trim(), you can match white space before and after a string with:

```
^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$
```

and then replace it with an empty string.

If you would like to remove any white space character anywhere in the string, then you could use the below as your match:

```
[\s\n\r]+
```

Comment: I am only able to give this user control a regex that either passes or fails based on my regex. So I need it to match on spaces and blanks, actually.

My current code is:
       `code`NoteEditMask='.+'
       `code`NoteResultMask='.+'
       `code`NoteResultMessage='You must enter a non-blank name entry.'

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to the other answers, I get the impression that you're looking to merely discard blank entries.

To that end, if the following regex matches, then the entry is invalid and should be discarded:

```
/^[\s\n\r]*$/
```

Comment: You are correct in what you are saying. That RegEx, however, doesn't seem to work with this dang control. Here is a quick paragraph for the control I am using and what it is expecting. Do you think there is a bug in it if your regex you just gave me won't work?

http://longboo.com/demo/ejs-treegrid/Doc/CellEdit.htm#CResultMask