# Only empty spaces should not be allowed in the input field

Tags: javascript

I have a regex `/^([A-Za-z\s-']{1,})$/`

This accepts alphabets, hyphen and apostrophes.

1. Having multiple spaces at the beginning of the string,in the middle and the end of the string is fine.
2. "Henry - Jackson's      Derby-'s" is also correct

I have only one problem to be fixed in this regex.

"If I enter only empty spaces in the input field it accepts that as well" - which is wrong

How can I avoid this?

Comment: See whether this can answer the question. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17555459/regex-to-allow-anything-except-blanks-or-all-spaces)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are allowing at least one of any character in the square brackets like that, including spaces, so even the string `" "` would be accepted.

You should do something like:
`/^\s*([A-Za-z\-\']+[A-Za-z\-\'\s]*)\s*$`

1. `^\s*`: initial spaces allowed
2. `[A-Za-z\-\']+`: at least one character in the given set (omit the space here so you have at least one character that is not a space)
3. `[A-Za-z\-\'\s]*`: zero or more characters in the given set
4. `\s*$`: trailing spaces and end of the string

Comment: `[A-Za-z\-\']+` could as well be simply `[A-Za-z\-\']` ;)